# Creating an event that changes a picture on mouseover

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create an event that changes the picture on mouse over.

```
var myImage = document.getElementById("mainImage");

var imageArray = ["_images/overlook.jpg","_images/winery_sign.jpg","_images/lunch.jpg",
                  "_images/bigSur.jpg","_images/flag_photo.jpg","_images/mission_look.jpg"];
var imageIndex = 0;

mainImage.mousover = function changeImage() {
    myImage.setAttribute("src",imageArray[imageIndex]);
    imageIndex++;
    if (imageIndex >= imageArray.length) {
        imageIndex = 0;
    }
}

// setInterval is also in milliseconds

mainImage.mousover = function () {
    var intervalHandle = setInterval(changeImage,1000);
}

myImage.onclick =  function() {
    clearInterval(intervalHandle);
};
```

`mainImage` is an object in HTML and the `changeImage` function changes current picture.

How should I change my code to make it work?

Comment: What are `mainImage` and `changeImage()`?

Comment: Yes pleas paste 'changeImage()` function, which help us for help you :).

Comment: mainImage is an object in html and changeimage is a function that change present picture

Comment: I think the down vote is because you did not provide enough information before editing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some type error like:

1. `mainImage.mousover =` is syntax error.
2. change `mainImage.mousover` to `mainImage.onmouseover`.

Also you should wrap your code in window.load event handler because it force browser execute your code after image has loaded.

Change code to following:

```
 window.onload = function () {
        var myImage = document.getElementById("mainImage");


        var imageArray = ["_images/overlook.jpg", "_images/winery_sign.jpg", "_images/lunch.jpg",
                          "_images/bigSur.jpg", "_images/flag_photo.jpg", "_images/mission_look.jpg"];
        var imageIndex = 0;

        //mainImage.mousover =

        function changeImage() {
            myImage.setAttribute("src", imageArray[imageIndex]);
            imageIndex++;
            if (imageIndex >= imageArray.length) {
                imageIndex = 0;
            }
        }

        // setInterval is also in milliseconds

        var intervalHandle;

        mainImage.onmouseover = function () {

            intervalHandle = MyImageInterval();

        }

        document.getElementById("stopButton").onclick = function () {
            clearInterval(intervalHandle);
        };

        function MyImageInterval() {
            return setInterval(changeImage, 1000);
        }
    }
```

Notice: You should add an input with type = "button" with Id="stopButton".

Comment: mamnoon Morteza.code works but after a while page gets crazy and changes the picture more nonstop also onclick event to stop it doesn't work

Comment: Khahesh. I change code. Now it should works. I add function called `MyImageInterval`, and change your mainImage.onmouseover event listener.

Comment: Chrome and Firefox.look,deleted my own code and replaced it with yours.

Comment: It does not works, because we expect that when user clicks image, image replacing will be stoped, while this click give us another `on mouse over` event. You shoul add another button for stopping button or use another strategy. I change my code now for that.

Answer (score 1):

removed the line that only says "mainImage.mousover =" in the middle

```
var myImage = document.getElementById("mainImage");

var imageArray = ["_images/overlook.jpg","_images/winery_sign.jpg","_images/lunch.jpg",
              "_images/bigSur.jpg","_images/flag_photo.jpg","_images/mission_look.jpg"];
var imageIndex = 0;



function changeImage() {
    myImage.setAttribute("src",imageArray[imageIndex]);
    imageIndex++;
    if (imageIndex >= imageArray.length) {
        imageIndex = 0;
    }
}

// setInterval is also in milliseconds

mainImage.onmousover = function () {

    var intervalHandle = setInterval(changeImage,1000);

}

myImage.onclick =  function() {
    clearInterval(intervalHandle);
};
```

Comment: i"m not familiar with JQ .changed the code to document.getElementById("mainImage").onmouseover = function(){
    this.setInterval(changeImage,1000);
};